# CSS - nested anchor tag link

Tags: css

I would like to create nested link inside a `<a>` tag

Example:

```
<a href="#">This is a link <a id="sup">sup text</a> end of the link</a>
```

css:

```
a#sup{
    color:#19578e;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 8pt;
    vertical-align: top;
}

a {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #19578e;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

However, like that only the "This is a link" point to the link...

Comment: You can't nest an anchor inside another anchor.

Comment: You can't nest anchor tags. This is invalid HTML. Use a SPAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a SPAN, since you cannot nest anchor tags.

```
<a href="#">This is a link <span id="sup">sup text</span> end of the link</a>
```

> Ok I'll use span, but how to make the span having the same propreties
>   than anchor tag when anchor tag is hover ?

Add the hover state to your CSS for the "sup" element.

```
a, a:hover #sup {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #19578e;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

If you have this in more than on place, you can simply use:

```
a, a:hover span { ... }
```

Comment: Ok I'll use span, but how to make the span having the same propreties than anchor tag when anchor tag is hover ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have `a` tags inside another `a` tag because [Nested Links are illegal](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)

You may use instead an `<span>` tag to make it work:

```
<a href="#">This is a link <span id="sup">sup text</span> end of the link</a>
```